# how to count the records of checked checkboxs in a grid

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a grid which is displaying the data from MYSQL db in PHP

Also i have provided a checkbox, if the user checks the checkbox, i need to show the how many records are checked

here is the php grid :

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action=''>
<table id='mytable'>
     <?php
       $sql_getData = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
       $result_getData = mysql_query();
       while($arr_data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_getData))
       {
             ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $arr_data['payment_id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $arr_data['payments'] ?></td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox' class='mycheckbox'></td>
                 <tr>
             <?php
       }
     ?>
     <tr><td>Total Checked</td><td>TOTAL_CHECKED_COUNT</td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write event like this:

## HTML:

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action=''>
    <table id='mytable'>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' name='mycheckbox' class='mycheckbox' />
            </td>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Total">Total Checked</td>
                    <td class="TotalCount"></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

## JQUERY:

```
$(".mycheckbox").change(function () {

    $(".TotalCount").text($(".mycheckbox:checked").length);

})
```

## FIDDLE:

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/uUWXE/2/)